# Correct SpecFlow's intellisense Regex

Tags: regex, bdd, specflow

I know that the intellisense (auto-completion) for the steps(and keywords) is using Regex to mach your custom ones. But when project grows in time it becomes realy annoying to scroll over your duplicated steps, with just different params.

Making the Regex non-greedy is the simplest solution I can think of.
Adding a `?` on a quantifier (`?`, `*` or `+`).

How to set your BDD engine to simply return only the first match? Is it possible to limit the number of step examples intellisense shows? I don't need 20 examples for one and the same step, first one (with the index brackets) is enough.

Example:

[image]

So if we have such repeating steps:

```
I login with 'admin' user
I login with 'default' user
I login with 'dealer' user
```

What we need is similar Regex `(.+)(?:'.+')(.+)`, matching everything except the parameters. In this case will return:

- group#1 *I login with*
- group#2 *user*

Comment: when you generate steps with `""` on the parameters, `Specflow` generates them with the correct `Regex`

Comment: Some examples of what your issue is might help understand your question. As it is I don't understand what the issue you are having is...

Comment: @SamHolder please see my updated question.

Comment: You say you don't need all the different steps, but each one will produce different step text won't it? As there are different parameters. I don't think what you want is possible but you might be able to come up with a different UI and submit a pull request

Comment: Even with different params, a Regex should be able to make the difference (escape everything between ``) and focus only on the rest of the Step name.

Comment: @ekostadinov but then you would have multiple matching steps, so which one would be invoked?

Comment: @SamHolder I'm assuming that the non-greedy Regex will catch the first mach :) Which is exactly the point of all previous talk.

Comment: @ekostadinov either I'm missing something or you are asking for something impossible. Maybe if you gave examples of the different steps and regexes you expect and details of how SpecFlow could decide which method to invoke for each regex it might help

Comment: @SamHolder i've updated the question.

Comment: @ekostadinov thanks do you have multiple step bindings for those steps or are they all bound to the same step? ie does you step have the regex `I login with '(.*)' user`?

Comment: Following OOP practices (DRY) - generic steps with parameter list. So yes, in this case many BDD steps bound to single reusable code step.

Comment: Since this is an open source project, you can change the behavior itself: I found [the StepSuggestionProvider](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/IdeIntegration/Vs2010Integration/StepSuggestions/StepSuggestionProvider.cs) class file on GitHub where you see `StepInstance` and `StepInstanceTemplate`. You are only interested in the Template (that is the [ⓦ] icon), so you can either change the `AddStepSuggestion` method by only adding templates, or add some `orderby` in the linq query for the `GetMatchingInstances` method that it will first display templates and than stepinstances.

Comment: Thanks I'll look at it.